# How to extract possible journeys from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe in below format

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'From': ['A','B','C','A','C','D','E'], 'To':['B','C','A','C','D','E','C'], 'User':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

I want to extract all possible journeys for a user.

```
Expected output:  [A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[A,B],[B,C],[C,A],[A,C],[C,D],[D,E],[E,C],[A,B,C],[B,C,A]…………
```

I tried heuristic model, i get the graph, but i am not able to convert into tabular data.

How can i achieve this using python operations or by using tabular format?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment, try showing some effort solving it on your own before asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: lol this is definitely not. It is complicated than i made it sound. But the logic remains the same as i asked

Comment: Well why dont you post your heuristic approach and maybe we can figure out how to turn it into tabular format.

Comment: here you go: {'A': (node:A connections:{A:[0.9722222222222222], B:[0.9565217391304348], D:[0.5], E:[0]}), 'B': (node:B connections:{B:[0.9583333333333334], E:[0.7], G:[0.631578947368421], F:[0]}), 'D': (node:D connections:{D:[0.6666666666666666], G:[0.5]}),.......... this is the node and conenctions of the sample output.. So i thought instead of looping on node connections pair, why not use simple approach and do it using FROM and TO. But you had to downvote and make it a homework problem lol

Comment: Please post the code that produces your journeys, the plain result doesn't exactly help here. You can also add additional information to your post by editing it.

Comment: it is a process mining approach which requires converting of dataframe into a required format to feed to model. it is a multistep process and i cant post entire process. I will post the part where dataframe is converted to graph

Comment: heu_net = heuristics_miner.apply_heu(log)
print(heu_net)
Above line gives the output which i pasted. In order to avoid these confusions, i asked a simple question whether if it is possible to extract such journeys from the data i pasted. Becasue EOD, i want to extract such journeys from heuristic model. If it is possible in simpler approach, why not use that

Comment: Well, then we go back to my original statement about trying to solve the problem on your own first. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask